# Derivative of $\ln\left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right)$

Tags: calculus

I know that the derivative of

$$f(x)=\ln(x) \ ,\ x>0$$

is just simply

$$f'(x)=\frac{dx}{x}$$

But how do you find the derivative for the function:

$$g(x)=\ln\left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right)\ , \ x>0$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** For $x>0$, we have $2x>0,x+1>0$. It is then the case  $$\begin{align}\log\frac{2x}{x+1}&=\log 2x-\log (1+x)\\&=\log x+\log 2-\log(1+x)\end{align} $$

Answer (score 3):

The trick hinted at by Peter Tamaroff in another answer is a clever one, but in general you use the chain rule to find the derivative of a composition:
$$(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x).$$
In your case, $f(x)=\ln x$ and $g(x)=2x/(1+x)$. Let us first find the derivatives of $f$ and $g$:
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= (\ln x)' = \frac{1}{x},\\
g'(x) &= \left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right)' = \frac{2(1+x) - 2x\cdot 1}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{2}{(1+x)^2}.
\end{align*}
Now we can apply the chain rule:
$$(f(g(x)))'=\frac{1}{\frac{2x}{1+x}} \cdot \frac{2}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{1+x}{2x}\cdot \frac{2}{(1+x)^2}= \frac{1}{x(1+x)}.$$
Note that $\frac{1}{x(1+x)}=\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{1+x},$ which is the answer you would get from Peter's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!